# Why would I use Redux Promise Middleware over Redux Promise?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-promise, redux-promise-middleware

I've used [Redux Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise), but it seems [Redux Promise Middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware) has more functionality like dispatching multiple actions with "PENDING" or "FULFILLED" appended.

Why would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally prefer Redux Promise Middleware as middleware as it enables optimistic updates; dispatches pending, fulfilled and rejected actions; and works well with with [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to chain async actions.

For example, you can use actions with `_PENDING` and `_FULFILLED` in reducers and update the UI with progress bar and similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to Redux Pomise Middleware. [Redux Auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto) has the same API as redux-promise-middleware and comes with a bunch of utility patterns under the hood to reduce the boilerplate you need to write.

The idea is to have each [action in a specific file](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#action-files). co-locating the server call in the file with reducer functions for "pending", "fulfilled" and "rejected". This makes handling promises very easy.

It also automatically attaches a [helper object (called "async")](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#handling-async-actions-in-your-ui) to the prototype of your state, allowing you to track in your UI, requeste transitions.

**Example:**

data/serverThing.js

```
export function pending (posts, payload){
  return posts
}

export function fulfilled (posts, payload, result){
  return result.serverResponse
}

export function rejected (posts, payload, error){
  return posts;
}

export function action (payload) {
  return Promise.resolve({serverResponse: [1,2,3,4]})
}
```

UI

```
import React  from "react"
import actions from 'redux-auto'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Foobar extends Component {

  const currentLoadingData = this.props.data.async.serverThing;

  if(currentLoadingData instanceof Error){
    var data = currentLoadingData.message
  } else if(true === currentLoadingData ){
    var data = "Loading..."
  } else {
    var data = this.porps.data.join();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>actions.data.serverThing()}>Do something!</button> 
        { data }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ( { data }) => {
  return { data }
};

export default connect( mapStateToProps )(Foobar);
```

> To understand the above source. redux-auto automatically creates actions and wires them to reduces based on the file structure. Where the folder name becomes the name of the property on the state. The files within a folder are actions to be performed on that part of the state.

Here is a complete [redux-auto: helloworld project](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto/tree/master/example)